# TYPO3 backend module language files are not loading

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I recently upgraded our TYPO3 portal from 6.2 to 7.6.18. My system uses a lot of old modules including [macina_banners](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/macina_banners), which, unfortunately, is not compatible with version 7+ and is also not under development anymore.

I fixed some deprecation issues like for all other modules, but the main problem is, that the language files are not loading for some reason:

**New record view:**

[image]

**Module view:**
[image]

The module itself is working, meaning, the already set up banners are displayed correctly.

The easiest way, would be to see, what are the files/variables its trying to load and can't find, but TYPO3 doesn't seem to give any of that info away.

I already tried adding *Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml*, but with no result so far. Its default language file location is ***LLL:EXT:macina_banners/locallang_db.php***.

Any other ideas how to debug/fix this?

*PS: This is how it looks, when I use the same code on the old v6.2.30 site:*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Typo3 7+ doesn't allow language files to be used from php files anymore and is requiring a strict XML structure.

I changed every entry from:

```
LLL:EXT:macina_banners/locallang_db.php:lang.string
```

to

```
LLL:EXT:macina_banners/locallang.xml:lang.string
```

and now the texts are working just fine.
[image]